# Unnecessary to adopt to datasource when using UIPickerView in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

From the documentation, it looks like when you uses `UIPickerView` class, you MUST adopt to `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol. However, even if I didn't adopt to `UIPickerViewDataSource` in my program, it seems that I was able to run my app correctly. For example, even if I write the following code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}
```

, and I do neither adopt to `UIPickerViewDataSource` in my header file nor write `_myPickerView.datasource = self;` in `viewDidLoad` method, I can run my app successfully, which means it has two components in view picker. (I adopted to `UIPickerViewDelegate` and wrote `_myPickerView.delegate = self;`.)

So is it unnecessary to adopt to datasource? And if that's the case, why? I know it's unnecessary to adopt to `UITableViewDelegate` when I use navigation controller since the parent class already adopts to the protocol - so is this the same reason?

For your information, even if the app works without adopting to datasource, I cannot use the "method name prediction functionality" in Xcode.

I inherited the class from `UIViewController`. My Xcode version is 5.0.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Malek, Yes, I meant to say that - `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` is from datasource, not delegate.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols serve two different purposes.
`UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol should be implemented as it provides meta-data (number of components, rows etc) required to generate the `UIPicker`.

`UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol on the other hand handles tasks for the `UIPicker` for example picker's value was changed then a delegate method would be called.

`UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol needs to be implemented so that we get the desired picker.
`UIPickerViewDelegate` is required if we want to implement some event based functionality on our picker.

If you don't implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods and set the `picker.delegate = self` then the app will crash as there is no implementation.

If you implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods and don't set the `picker.delegate = self` then the app will run but the app won't respond to events on the picker.

If you don't implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods and set the `picker.datasource = self` the app will crash as there is no implementation.

If you implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods and don't set the `picker.datasource = self` then the app will run but the picker will appear empty as there was no meta-data available to make the picker.